# How to refresh inside v-for nativescript vue

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, page-refresh, v-for

I'm trying to make a chat function for my app. To display the message I have a v-for loop for al the messages. But when I add a message it doesn't get displayed on the page.

In the template is use a v-for model as shown below.

```
     <WrapLayout v-for="(message, index) of getMessages" v-bind:key="index">
      <StackLayout  class="chat-box-content">
        <Label
          class="text-content body"
          textWrap="true"
          :text="message.message"
        />
      </StackLayout>
    </WrapLayout>
```

In the v-for model i get the messages from the computed method getMessages(). When a message is added the console log "message added" is shown. so the computed method sees that a message is added but it doesn't get shown on my page.

```
computed: {   
 getMessages() {
  let messages;
  let chats = store.getters.getChats;
  chats.forEach((element) => {
    if (element.chatId === this.chatId) {
      console.log("message added")
      messages = element.messages;
    }
  });
  return messages;
},
```

I get messages out of my store.ts. Messages is part of chats.

```
export interface IChat {
chatId: string,
lastMessage: string,
timestamp: string,
senderName: string,
members: [{
    userId: string,
    name: string
}],
messages: [{
    message: string,
    sender: string,
    timestamp: string,
}],
```

}

Update:

So apparently my v-for does reload when a message is added, but not on the first time i acces the page.

- I start the app for the first time, navigate to my chat, send a message, message does not get shown on the screen.
- I click on the back button, navigate to chats again, send a new message, message now gets shown on screen.

Annyone an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Could you please add the code snippets in the post?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays

Comment: @RobertRocha is this the same for returning arrays with an computed element. The computed function runs, but it doesn't update anything on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check that computed property `getMassages` has the structure you expect?
It looks like you're assuming it's
`[{message:"hello"}, ...]` is that correct?
Please add more code to give better context.

Comment: Yes I added the code of IChat in my question above. Messages is part of IChat.